# Apache : Recover “sites-enabled” config files

Tags: apache-2.2

I was cleaning up on one of my older servers when I realized that there was a lot of stuff in the "sites-available" config folder that wasn't being used, and since everything I needed and rarely modified was in the "sites-enabled" folder, I ran a "rm -rf *" on the "sites-available" folder...

BAD IDEA, it happens that the files in "sites-enabled" were actually symbolic links to the ones in "sites-available", the ones I just deleted.

The good news is that I haven't applied the changes or restarted apache yet, so all my sites are still up. Is there a way to recover these file from the currently running apache process ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know It is late, but there is a `mod_info`, which shall give you what you want, but it obviously has to be loaded first anyway :)

Comment: Since the files were deleted, looks like mod_info would not have worked either. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v1326/manual/misc/FAQ.html#no-info-directives.. thanks though, now I know of 1 more apache module

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use tool like `ddrescue`, because I think there is no way how to get configuration from running apache, but I can be wrong.

Comment: I can't comment your post, so which filesystem have you got?
If it's ext4/3 than `extundelete`, see http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/